# Function to get the number of animals in python

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

Hello these functions return the number of pigs and chickens based on the input of these two animals' heads and legs. I am really new to python. I can't understand how it works. Can you explain this elaborately?

```
def solve(numLegs, numHeads):
    for numChick in range(0, numHeads + 1):
        numPigs = numHeads - numChicks
        totLegs = 4 * numPigs + 2* numChicks
        if totLegs == numLegs:
           return [numPigs, numChicks]
    return[None, None]

def barnYard():
    heads = int(raw_input('Enter number of heads:'))
    legs = int(raw_input('Enter number of legs:'))
    pigs, chickens = solve(legs, heads)
    if pigs = None:
       print 'there is no solution'
    else:
        print 'number of pigs:' , pigs
        pirnt 'number of chickes:', chickens
```

So when i run the barnYard function it asks number of heads so i put 20 heads and then put 56 legs. It prints number of pigs 8 and number chickens  12. But i really can't understand how it reaches at this stage. Specially the `solve()` function. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'll tell you right now, that's a *very* slow algorithm for solving this, and it can be done much faster, in O(1) time actually. Also, this question doesn't belong on S.O. because it's way too broad in scope.

Comment: *Walk through* the code line by line, use a pencil and paper to write down *variable* values at each step.  That should get you started. suggest you use small numbers of heads and legs.  If you have gotten this far in the tutorial/class/course/mooc you should be able to walk through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically:

```
def solve(numLegs, numHeads):
    for numChick in range(0, numHeads + 1): #for every number in the range 0 - the number of heads + 1, numChick = that number
        numPigs = numHeads - numChicks #the number of Pigs equals the number of heads entered minus the current number
        totLegs = 4 * numPigs + 2* numChicks #the amount of legs is 4(amount of legs) * number of heads + 2(chicken legs) * the current number
        if totLegs == numLegs: if the pigs legs + the chicken legs = the total number of legs, 
           return [numPigs, numChicks] #return the number of pigs and chickens
    return[None, None] #else, return none, triggering "no solution"

def barnYard():
    heads = int(raw_input('Enter number of heads:')) #
    legs = int(raw_input('Enter number of legs:'))
    pigs, chickens = solve(legs, heads)
    if pigs = None:
       print 'there is no solution'
    else:
        print 'number of pigs:' , pigs
        pirnt 'number of chickes:', chickens
```

So:

Basically, it will run the function over and over until the amount of legs calculated equals the total amount of legs entered. If it never equals up, it just returns [none, none]. (return [numPigs, numChicks] breaks the for loop)

**Edit:**
I tried taking out the +1  in line 2 and it still worked just fine.

Comment: If I missed something please tell me

Comment: Moris can you explain this: for numChick in range(0, numHeads + 1): more broadly with values(numbers input from the BarnYard function for example). why it adds +1?

Comment: @wwii I am with pencil. But stuck at some points.